# Predator's Rapport and counters

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose [Predator's Rapport](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366233)'s target has counters (for example, a few +1/+1 counters). Do the counters count when calculating the gained life? I thought power and toughness do not change after adding counters.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. When a card refers to any creature's power or toughness, it always means the creature's current power or toughness, not what is printed on the card. This includes any +1/+1, -1/-1 or other counters that modify power and toughness; any equipment or enchantments attached to the creature that modify power and/or toughness, and any effects from cards such as [Giant Growth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Giant%20Growth), [Glorious Anthem](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Glorious%20Anthem), or [Bile Blight](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bile%20Blight).

Note that damage on a creature does *not* change its toughness.

Answer (score 1):

+1/+1 counters count for power and toughness. The power and toughness of a creature are modified by counters in Layer 7. You can also change the P/T with other spells, such as [Giant Growth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Giant%20Growth). Giant growth is also applied in Layer 7.

It's hard to explain in a few sentences, but more info about the layer system is explained in [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150916173223/http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=judge/article/20091105a).

Comment: You do not need to know about layers to answer this question. All you need to know is that power means power, not base power.

Comment: P/T on its own is not a CDA, it's simply a characteristic. Some creatures _have_ a CDA that defines its P/T (the various goyfs, for example), but that doesn't make P/T a CDA in the general case.

Comment: Counters are still applied in Layer 7, despite not being a CDA. I should be able to clean this answer up a bit. Oh, and Giant Growth happens to be applied in the same layer (Layer 7), so I fixed that too.

Comment: @Jefromi You do need to know about layers if the creature in question is an Ogre. Because Ogres are like onions: they have layers.